# Access Gmail in C

Tags: c, http, gmail

Is there an equivalent for the python [libgmail](http://libgmail.sourceforge.net/) in “C”?

**Edit:**
 I am trying to achieve the equivalent of [GmailFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GmailFS) in C.

Appreciate if you can point me to an open source library. This is for a hobby project.

Answer (score 2):

I think this helps

[Pop3 Gmail C](http://pop3-gmail-c.qarchive.org/)

Client/Server Comm Lib for C/C++ 6.0

Comment: POP library doesn’t help. I need one that can access through HTTP and SSL. With POP you can’t search.